# copy_if in C++...having troubles

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the copy_if in my program. I would like to copy every 3 elements the values of one array into another one.

basically, I wrote a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>   

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int16_t *array;
    int16_t *new_array;

    array = new int16_t[10]();
    new_array = new int16_t[4]();

    array[0] = 9;
    array[1] = 1;
    array[2] = 50;
    array[3] = 30;
    array[4] = 3;
    array[5] = 24;
    array[6] = 66;
    array[7] = 73;
    array[8] = 108;
    array[9] = 10;

    copy_if(array, array+9, new_array, [&] (const int& i) -> bool 
    { size_t index = i -array[0]; return index % 3 == 0; });

    for (int jj = 0; jj < 4; jj++) {
        cout << "new_array[" << jj << "] = " << new_array[jj] << endl;
    }
}
```

The final result SHOULD be like

```
new_array[0] = 9
new_array[1] = 30
new_array[2] = 66
new_array[3] = 10
```

but I obtain:

```
new_array[0] = 9
new_array[1] = 30
new_array[2] = 24
new_array[3] = 66
```

I saw many times the copy_if used with vector but problay i'm missing something since i'm using pointers.

Comment: What happened when you tried the equivalent code with a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is the element, not a pointer to it. Your predicate is wrong, since it relies on the values of the array elements, not their position. It should be:

```
size_t index = &i - &array[0]; return index % 3 == 0;
```

Now it calculates the position with pointer arithmetic. Bear in mind that such a predicate can only work for contiguous storage: A c-array, a `std::array` or a `std::vector`.

Comment: If I try your code, it does not compile giving me an error....invialid operand of types ... to binary operator. Ok for the second, clear :)

Comment: @alexmark - That's because your arrays are `int16_t`, and the operands a `const int&`. Fix the types here. That const reference means you have a conversion and a temporary hidden inside the algorithm.

Comment: ok...i did it while you were writing me eheheheh. it works. thanks

Comment: @alexmark - Keep the const. It's good practice. Setting to `int16_6` is enough.